# How do I find the exponent of a mod

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I have :

${(g^{XB} \bmod P)}^{RA} \bmod P = 12 $

If : $XB =4 $,  $g=9$ , $P =23$

How do I find the value of $RA$ in terms of $g$ ?

I have tried and found this to be correct direction, but I can't seem to actually get it to work with the numbers
 $ ({g^{XB}}^{RA}\bmod P)^{XB^{-1}} = g^{RA} \bmod P$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

First compute $\;9^4\bmod23=(9^2\bmod23)^2=(-11)^2\bmod 23=6\bmod 23$.

Then determine the order of $6\bmod 23$: it is a divisor of $\varphi(23)=22$, so it can be $2$, $11$ or $22$. Using the *fast exponentiation algorithm* mod. $23$, you'll find it has order $11$. So you have to make the list of powers of $6\bmod 23$, possibly up to the exponent $10$, until you obtain $12$. The first two powers are comparatively easy…